# Join column from a table with concat columns from another one

Tags: postgresql

I try to match names from a table with a concatenation of columns in another table with Postgres.

**What I have:**

Table A:

```
id,name
1,John Smith
2,Laura Doe Van Renburg
3,Laura Thorpe
4,Carl Leonard Dong
```

Table B:

```
id,firstname,lastname
1,Aloys,Smith
2,Laura,Doe Van Renburg
3,Pedro,De Mung
4,Carl Leonard, Dong
```

**The result I expect**

```
Laura Doe Van Renburg
Carl Leonard Dong
```

**What I tried**

I think concatening the columns firstname and lastname from table B could help but I can't figure out what the correct syntax is.

```
select A.name from A 
  join (select concat(firstname,' ',lastname) from B) as firstandlast 
  on a.name = firstandlast;
```

But it's not the correct way. Any clue would be welcome!

Comment: It looks like you are just removing commas and numbers. Is there more depth to the question?

Comment: As firstnames and names are concatenated in table A,  I don't know how to compare them with the columns 2 and 3 from table B. Is there a simpler way than concat?

Comment: No clue, sorry! :(

Comment: Was just hoping your problem could be solved by simple regex for , and [0-9] :) but clearly not. Hopefully you find a good answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
select a.name 
from table_a a
  join table_b b on concat(b.firstname, ' ', b.lastname) = a.name
```

Comment: Simple and effective! Many thanks for your help.